# How do I know if I'm running in a web environment?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm wondering if someone has a method for detecting whether or not a thread is running in a web environment.

```
HttpContext.Current
```

is not reliable because I'm making these checks in background threads where there is no HttpContext. It seems like

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId
```

is pretty reliable (if it is null then I'm not in a web app), but I'm wondering if anyone else has some tried and true technique.

By the way, I'll be using this for a variety of things. For example this code:

```
if (HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId != null)
        {
            config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        }
        else
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        }
```

Thx
Joni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HostingEnvironment.IsHosted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.ishosted), I think it will work as expected

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be what I was looking for.